# Typecasting pointers in linked list of structures

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, structure

The problem stated that I needed two structures, STRUCTURE1 and STRUCTURE2 (original I know). STRUCTURE1 holds 5 floats values(not an array) and one pointer. STRUCTURE2 holds 1 float value and one pointer to another STRUCTURE2 type. I also needed an array of pointers in which each element points to a STRUCTURE1. Then each first STRUCTURE1 points to another STRUCTURE1, but then THAT STRUCTURE1 needs to point to a STRUCTURE2 (this is where the type cast comes in).

Below is the important parts of my code, the problem (where I'm getting an error at least) is in the printToFile() at the `trav2 = (STRUCT2*)trav1->next;` part where I get a segmentation fault.

```
   void main(){
      STRUCT1 *ptr[20] = {NULL};  //Array of pointers that point to type STRUCT1
      float min, max;
      int i, j, answer;
      for(i = 0; i < 19; i++){   //19 to leave the 20th array spot for NULL
        printf("\nWould you like to add 2 more sets of numbers?\n");
        printf("1: Yes\n");
        printf("2: No\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        if(answer == 1){
          printf("\nFirst set of numbers:\n");
          ptr[i] = getData();
          printf("\nSecond set of numbers:\n");
          ptr[i]->next = getData();
          min = getMin(ptr[i]);
          max = getMin(ptr[i]->next);
          STRUCT2 *trav;
          trav = (STRUCT2*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));
          trav = (STRUCT2*)ptr[i]->next;
          trav->next = assignMin(min);
          trav = trav->next;
          trav->next = assignMax(max);
        }else{
          break;
        }
      }
      printToFile(ptr);
      printf("\nProgram Done\n");
    }

STRUCT1* getData(){
  STRUCT1 *newStruct;
  newStruct = (STRUCT1*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));
  float num;
      printf("Enter number 1: ");
      scanf("%f", &num);
      newStruct->f1 = num;
      printf("Enter number 2: ");
      scanf("%f", &num);
      newStruct->f2 = num;
      printf("Enter number 3: ");
      scanf("%f", &num);
      newStruct->f3 = num;
      printf("Enter number 4: ");
      scanf("%f", &num);
      newStruct->f4 = num;
      printf("Enter number 5: ");
      scanf("%f", &num);
      newStruct->f5 = num;

      return newStruct;
}

void printToFile(STRUCT1 *ptr[]){
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen("structure.txt", "w");
  int i, j;
  STRUCT1 *trav1;
  STRUCT2 *trav2;
  trav1 = (STRUCT1*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));
  trav2 = (STRUCT2*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT2));

  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    fprintf(f, "%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f\n", ptr[i]->f1, ptr[i]->f2, ptr[i]->f3, ptr[i]->f4, ptr[i]->f5);
    trav1 = ptr[i]->next;
    fprintf(f, "%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f\n", trav1->f1, trav1->f2, trav1->f3, trav1->f4, trav1->f5);
    trav2 = (STRUCT2*)trav1->next;
    fprintf(f, "Minimum of first number set: %.3f\n", trav2->f1);
    trav2 = trav2->next;
    fprintf(f, "Maximum of second number set: %.3f\n", trav2->f1);
    fprintf(f, "\n");    
  }
}
```

This could all be very very wrong but my professor never talked about pointers pointing to different types, and also the section on structures was short. Hopefully its not completely botched and only needs a few things here and there.

Anyone think they see where it went wrong?

Comment: It appears he also never talked about `free()`. That aside, it would probably help readability if you included the structure definitions in  the code-portion of your question.

Comment: *Many* things wrong, starting with incomplete code. Neither `assignMin()` nor `assignMax()` are included in the post, likewise the structures. Your dynamically allocating memory where it doesn't need to be, and where it does, you're immediately overwriting the allocations with uninitialized values (things like `trav = (STRUCT2*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));` immediately followed by `trav = (STRUCT2*)ptr[i]->next;` You never initialize `newStruct->next` for allocations in `getData()`, and there isn't a `free()` anywhere in this. I would suggest some **serious** time in a debugger and a textbook.

Comment: I realize the code is really bad. Its also the first assignment with structures and linked lists. I didn't include the structure code or the other functions because that wasn't where the problem was and the structures only had definitions for float values.

I have since made the program work, probably not in the most efficient way but I got rid of the useless memory allocations and added freeing of memory. 

I apologize if my poor coding offended anyone lol but I do thank you for the help because it DID help me.

Comment: No offense, Zack. The sooner you see what is wrong the sooner you'll learn to do it right. The combination of (a) Learning from known-good code examples and styles and (b) writing your own code, will help tremendously. Its one thing to have some lame book or prof say "this is the way". But I cannot stress this enough: learn from known-good code. Look for holes and problems in code you suspect isn't so good, and above all, learn good debugging habits. The latter seems to be completely skipped in academia and thats a shame. Few things will serve you better than having solid ways of finding bugs.

Comment: The sane way to do this is to split `STRUCT1` into `STRUCT1a` and `STRUCT1b`, and have `STRUCT1a` have a pointer to `STRUCT1b` which has a pointer to `STRUCT2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in the question, structure definitions and code populating these structures are missing. The casts are not necessarily wrong. However, you can use different pointers to access either type of structures:

```
   if (ptr->next_st1 != NULL) {
      trav1 = ptr->next_st1;
   } else if (ptr->next_st2 != NULL) {
      trav2 = ptr->next_st2;
   }
```

as a side note, the allocations you do here:

```
  trav1 = (STRUCT1*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));
  trav2 = (STRUCT2*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT2));

  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    /* ... */
    trav1 = ptr[i]->next;
    /* ... */
```

are not necessary since you are assigning pointers to already allocated regions (`trav1 = ptr[i]->next`). Due to this assignment, you are leaking memory because you lose the pointers to malloced chunks. In this case `malloc` is not necessary, but when it is necessary you should have a corresponding `free()` call.

Comment: Its not just due to that assignment. Assuming that was fixed, it would still leak, as there isn't a `free()` anywhere in this source.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
trav = (STRUCT2*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT1));
```

Here, `tray` as a `STRUCT2` pointer and allocate memory for `STRUCT1`. Better use `sizeof(STRUCT2)`.